# PHP - Can't get sockets to work properly when connected via OVPN

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, vpn, openvpn

I have two machines, one is a server, the other a laptop. They are both on my local network. The laptop also has a virtual machine.

I have the following code, which runs on the virtual machine in my laptop as a result of me opening a web page (on my laptop) that points to the webserver running on the virtual machine:

```
$header=$this->getHeader();
$this->socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
socket_set_timeout($this->socket, 0, 10000);
fwrite($this->socket, $header);
usleep(50000);
$response = fread($this->socket, 15000);
```

`$host` is the server, and there is a PHP websockets server there listening for connections.

If I run this all over my local network (192.168.0.x) everything works fine. The problem is when I try to connect via openvpn (10.122.122.x).

I have traced what's happening and looking through the various logs I can confirm that the server is receiving the request from the VM in the laptop, it reads the `$header` data correctly and responds appropriately, however `fread($this->socket, 15000);` returns nothing. I can't find anything in the logs that indicates an issue, and the code continues to run (just without being connected).

In terms of the VPN, it all appears to be working fine. I can ssh to the VPN IP and indeed the `fwrite($this->socket, $header);` part of the code works fine.

Just to confuse things further, the javascript code that runs in the browser on my laptop to listen for websockets messages works fine over the VPN! The problem seems to be only the php code that is running on my virtual machine.

Where else can I look to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: This may be a routing issue, make sure that the server knows how to find the virtual machine via the network (can you ping it from the server).

Comment: As I understand it, the client always initiates and the server only responds, so I'm not convinced it's a routing issue. Aside from that, if I am not using the VPN, the server definitely has no way to initiate a connection to the virtual machine, but the virtual machine receives messages. That all said, If I switch to VPN, I do have a route, as I am able SSH to the virtual machine from the server using the VPN IP address.